# Phase diagram contradicts analytical results

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics, steady-state

Consider the following dynamic system
\begin{align}
 f(x,y) = \left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{2y} - x\right), \frac{10y^2 - 12xy + 3}{24y - 16x}\right).
\end{align}
There exists a steady state at $(x_\infty,y_\infty) = (\sqrt{30}/6,\sqrt{30}/10)$ such that $f(x_\infty,y_\infty) = (0,0)$.
The jacobian at the steady state reads
\begin{align}
\mathrm J_f(x_\infty,y_\infty) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{1}{4} & -\frac{5}{12}\\
\frac{9}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
Now note that the determinante is positive $\mathrm D_\infty = \mathrm{det}(\mathrm J_f(x_\infty,y_\infty)) = 15/8$, the trace negative $\mathrm T_\infty = \mathrm{trace}(\mathrm J_f(x_\infty,y_\infty)) = -1/4$ and $\mathrm D_\infty - \mathrm T_\infty^2/4 = 119/64$ such that according to the [Poincare diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_theory) the steady state is a spiral sink.

When I consider a [streamslice](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamslice.html) plot, however, it is evident that the steady state is unstable.
What am I missing?
[image]

The Matlab code reads:

```
clear all; clc;
syms x y
dx = (1/(2*y) - x)/4;
dy = (10*y^2 - 12*x*y + 3)/(24*y-16*x);
xss = sqrt(30)/6;
yss = sqrt(30)/10;
J = jacobian([dx,dy],[x,y]);
Jss = subs(J,[x,y],[xss,yss]);
D = det(Jss);
T = trace(Jss);
C = D - T^2/4;

dx_fun = matlabFunction(dx);
dy_fun = matlabFunction(dy);

X_max = 2;
Y_max = 2;
N = 50;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0.01,X_max,N),linspace(0.01,Y_max,N));

M = 50;
[start_x,start_y] = meshgrid(linspace(0.01,X_max,M),linspace(0.01,Y_max,M));
dX = dx_fun(X,Y);
dY = dy_fun(X,Y);

hold on
figure(1)
streamslice(X,Y,dX,dY)
plot(xss,yss,'r*')
xlim([0 X_max])
ylim([0 Y_max])
%saveas(gcf,'poin.png')
```

Comment: I think to begin with, your viewing window is too large to see the behavior of the linearization.

Comment: It would help if you added the plots of the null-clines of both components and of the singular line $y=2x/3$ of the zero set of the second denominator to the plot. Then you would see how close the equilibrium point is to the singular set and that the lines close to the equilibrium are severely distorted by the singularity, so that you can conclude nothing from the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed point is stable as your analysis predicts—it's just not globally stable.

This is clear if you zoom in to the fixed point a little:

[image]